# input element 1 by 1 from other function w/o for loop

Tags: function, matlab, for-loop, scope

I have a function that calculates an array of numbers (randparam) that I want to input element by element into another function that does a simulation.

For example

```
function [randparam] = arraycode

code 

randparam = results of code 
% randparam is now a 1x1001 vector. 

end
```

next I want to input randparam 1 by 1 into my simulation function

```
function simulation 

x = constant + constant * randparam + constant

return 
end
```

What makes this difficult for me is because of the return command in the simulation function, it only calculates one step of the equation x above, returns the result into another function, call it integrator, and then the integrator function will call simulation function again to calculate x.

so the integrator function might look like

```
function integrator (x)
y = simulation(x) * 5
u = y+10
yy = simulation(x) * 10 + u

end
```

As you can see, integrator function calls the simulation function twice. which creates two problems for me:

1. If I create a for loop in the simulation function where I input element by element using   something like:

   for i = 1:100

   x = constant + constant * randparam(i) + constant

   return
   end

then every time my integrator function calls my simulation function again, my for loop starts at 1 all over again.

2.If I some how kept i in my base workspace so that my for loop in my simulation function    would know to step up from 1, then my y and yy functions would have different x inputs because as soon as it would be called the second time for yy, then i would now be i+1 thanks to the call due to y.

Is there a way to avoid for loops in this scenario? One potential solution to problem number two is to duplicate the script but with a different name, and have my for loop use a different variable, but that seems rather inefficient.

Hope I made this clear.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you generically want to apply the same function to each element of an array and there **isn't already a built in vectorized way to do it**, you *could* use `arrayfun` (although often a simple `for` loop is faster and more readable):

```
%# randparam is a 1x1001 vector. 
%#next I want to input randparam 1 by 1 into my simulation function
function simulation 
    x = constant + constant * randparam + constant
    return 
end
```

(Note: ask yourself what this function can possibly be doing, since it isn't returning a value and MATLAB doesn't pass by reference.)  This is what `arrayfun` is for: applying a function to each element of an array (or vector, in this case).  Again, you should make sure in your case that it makes sense to do this, rather than an explicit loop.

```
function simulation(input_val)
#% your stuff
end


sim_results = arrayfun( @simulation, randparam);
```

Of course, the way you've written it, the line

```
x = constant + constant*randparam + constant;
```

can (and will) be done vectorized - if you give it a vector or matrix, a vector or matrix will be the result.

**Second** it seems that you're not clear on the "scope" of function variables in MATLAB.  If you call a function, a clean workspace is created.  So `x` from one function isn't automatically available within another function you call.  Variables also go out of scope at the end of a function, so using `x` within a function doesn't change/overwrite a variable `x` that exists outside that function.  And **multiple invocations of a function each have their own workspace**.

Comment: This "first" point isn't valid. `arrayfun` is often slower than a for loop, assuming memory is preallocated. For example, `y = arrayfun(@sin, x)` is slower than `y = zeros(1, numel(x)); for j = 1:numel(x); y(j) = sin(x(j)); end`

Comment: @RobDiPietro This is true in my experience; however the question specifies "w/o for loop".  And as I pointed out, the operation within the `simulation` function implicitly supports the vectorized form.

Comment: That's true; maybe the answer should just be reworded a bit. I think the first part of your answer heavily suggests that `arrayfun` is the right way to apply a function over an array, but in reality this produces slower _and_ less readable code.

Comment: @RobDiPietro Edited.  I agree that in the case of 1D arrays, `arrayfun` can be less readable, though I'd argue that anyone who regularly uses MATLAB would easily see the operation correctly. With N-D arrays it is often *much* more readable than N levels of nested `for` loops. When it comes to this question though, I suspect the issue of variable scope is much more important to the question-asker. The suggestion of duplicating a script and using a different variable name certainly suggests so.

Comment: Hi tmpearce, thanks for your response. I am having difficulty with variable scope and I am not sure how I can implement the arrayfun function properly. It may just be easier to do this with a for loop I suppose. I just want to make sure I am clear however, I do not want to pass the 1x1001 vector of random parameters and compute it in vectorized from. The reason I need it element by element is that the particular computation that is utilizing the random param values is called on many times to make the final result and is computed in a step wise fashion. I would have to change much of the code

Comment: to instead utilize the vectorized form, which I don't want to do. Lastly, in terms of variable scope, and regarding your second point, I am aware of what happens to variable x within the function after the function is terminated. That is the problem, I want to be able to continue my loop (or arrayfun call) even when the function is called to run again so that it knows that value of i that it was previously on. As you pointed out, within a function, this is not possible because as soon as it is called upon, it starts over. Therefore, how might I utilize arrayfun, or a for loop such that

Comment: i can compute element by element of my rand parm vector, even it the function it is called upon has to start over? Or do I need to fundamentally restructure things? Note: You have already answered why arrayfun is relevant here, but I have not been successful implementing it, so if possible, I need a bit more explanation. Thank you

Comment: @Joe, I suggest taking another look at partially vectorizing here.  For example, compute the random parameter in vectorized form *once*, then use it element-by-element in your loop by indexing into it. That is, within the loop where you call `integration`, grab `param(i)` and pass it as a parameter to `integration`. You don't have to vectorize *all* the code just because one step is vectorized. In fact, it is often easiest to just change one part at a time.

Comment: Hi tmpearce, I eventually figured it out. The problem was that the example I gave was unclear and didn't paint a representative picture of my problem. Anyhow, your comments and responses to my question got me thinking more about variable scope and alternative ways to think about the problem. I know for certain that if I had clearly laid out the problem, you all would have easily showed me the solution - however it was a bit more satisfying to see it myself, though you gave me some prodding about understanding variable scope. Thanks tmpearce for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a loop at the integrator level?

```
function integrator (x)

for i=1:length(x)
    y = simulation(x(i)) * 5
    u = y+10
    yy = simulation(x(i)) * 10 + u
end
```

And pass your entire randparm into integrator?  It's not clear from your question whether you want `simulation` to return the same value when given the same input, or whether you want it step twice with the same input, or whether you want a fresh input on every call.  It is also not clear if `simulation` keeps any internal state.  The way you've written the example, simulation depends only on the input value, not on any previous inputs or outputs, which would make it trivial to vectorize.  If we're all missing the boat, please edit your question with more refined example code.

Comment: Sorry Peter, you are correct that I didn't clearly lay out the problem. As I was about to try to redefine my problem, I realized something else I could try, and it worked, but it was along the lines of your response. Thanks very much for your time.